# If not x % y: Do something

Tags: python, modulo

I have a question about the following statement in Python

```
if not x % y: 
    # do something
```

After seeing this in a piece of code and experimenting I found that if modulo evaluates to anything but zero it'll skip the "do something" code.

My question is, is there a general rule about If and If not statements with implied conditions and are there any good references for Python "tricks" like this?

I apologize about the broad question but this threw me for a loop when I first saw it. I would like to learn as many of these short hand tricks as I can!

Comment: Documentation reference confirming the answers [here in section 5.1](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `None` is false.
- Numbers that are not zero are considered true; `0` is false
- Strings with any content are true; `""` is false
- Containers with anything in them are true; `[]`, `()`, and `{}` (and other empty containers) are false

This can be overridden on your own types by defining `__len__()` or `__nonzero__()` (the latter is named `__bool__()` in Python 3). You could even define, for example, a zero that evaluates as true:

```
class trueint(int):
    def __nonzero__(self):
        return True
    __bool__ = __nonzero__    # Python 3

truezero = trueint(0)

if truezero:
    print("yep, this zero is true!")
```

You probably *shouldn't* do this, as it will confuse Python programmers, but you *could.*

Comment: to be clear, saying - None is false, 0 is false, "" is false - are not correct. they *evaluate* to false.

Comment: The string one is just a special case of the container one.

Comment: @Hammerite: True, but I thought I'd call it out specially 'cause it might not be obvious to someone who is asking this question to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as an "implied condition" in Python; there are true values, and there are false values.

These are false:

- `None`
- 0 (or any number equal to it)
- Empty sequences (`''`, `u''`, `b''`, `[]`, `()`), mappings (`{}`), or sets (`{,}`)
- Objects that return false from their `__nonzero__()` method

Anything else should be considered true until proven otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is called Truthiness in Python: http://www.udacity.com/wiki/CS258%20Truthiness%20in%20Python